# React 16.4 getDerivedStateFromProps and controlled components

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

Recently i've refactored my Checkbox component to use the new **getDerivedStateFromProps** static method instead of the deprecated **componentWillReceiveProps**.

**Now i'm experiencing some issues:**

**1.** I had to save another previousValue in the component state and compare it each time with the new values, coming from state or props - (otherwise it won't work, since getDerivedStateFromProps is invoked upon each update, also state change).

**2.** getDerivedStateFromProps is called 4 times per checkbox change which seems like a waste...

What am i missing here?

[code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-yucxwd)

Comment: Fixed by removing inner state and getDetivedStateFromProps and using only the parent's state.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by removing inner state and getDetivedStateFromProps and using only the parent's state.
[fixed-code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-vfse9a)